# Spinnaker to deploy to Cloud Foundry/IBM Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, spinnaker

I'm interested in using Spinnaker to deploy applications to IBM Bluemix. I've read the [spinnaker doc](http://www.spinnaker.io/v1.0/docs/target-deployment-setup#section-cloud-foundry-platform-setup) about target deployment setup, and have tried that, but I don't understand the part about having to deploy the [Spring Cloud Spinnaker app](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-spinnaker) to IBM Bluemix. The `cf push` failed on Bluemix. It does work pushing to Pivotal.

My main lack of understanding is that I would like to install Spinnaker to a local physical machine and have it deploy microservice applications to IBM Bluemix. I thought I could follow the [installation documentation](http://www.spinnaker.io/docs/creating-a-spinnaker-instance) and edit the spinnaker-local.yml file to have it point at Bluemix.

Has anybody used Spinnaker in a scenario like mine and have any advice? Is this feature available?

Comment: One scope is to deploy Spinnaker into your cloud. The other is to use Spinnaker to deploy apps into your cloud. I don't know if those are two different questions to post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's also possible to build and run Spring Cloud Spinnaker on your local machine, and then use it to deploy Spinnaker to any Cloud Foundry compliant instance you can see.

Just be sure to have run `./build_spinnaker.sh all`, or you won't have the Spinnaker modules for deployment.

I personally haven't tested `cf push` on anything other than PWS and PCF, so I'm not sure why that doesn't work.